# How do I successfully add RealmSwift to Xcode?

Tags: macos, realm

I would like to add RealmSwift to an experimental Xcode project (for Mac OS X Yosemite) and have tried to follow the installation instructions on the Realm website.

I have downloaded the Swift version of Realm and dragged the framework to Xcode correctly.

I have set the Framework search paths to point to the new framework.
On trying to run, Xcode trips up with a code sign error, exit code 1.

I have not added anything else to a standard Xcode template / Cocoa (non-document) application using Swift and storyboards - its just a bog-standard appDelegate Xcode template at the moment without any added code other than the Realm framework. I have searched endlessly around SO and across the internet in general but most help out there concentrates on iOS.

I am using Xcode 6.3.2 build 6D2105 and OS X 10.10.4.

The error log looks like this:

> Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules"
>   (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
>   /Users/bobavery/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RealmTest-hffxikloaikapxcsotbcfqpezrba/Build/Products/Debug/RealmTest.app/Contents/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Versions/A:
>   code object is not signed at all In subcomponent:
>   /Users/bobavery/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RealmTest-hffxikloaikapxcsotbcfqpezrba/Build/Products/Debug/RealmTest.app/Contents/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Realm.framework
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Any pointers would be very welcome!

Comment: [I work at Realm] Have you tried alternative installation methods? CocoaPods would be an obvious choice. In the meantime, we'll double check our instructions to make sure they're correct for your scenario (Swift, OS X, prebuilt binaries).

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem before.. and the documentation is working allright.. i think there something wrong on the way your adding the framework.. on a new xcode project.. Go to General.. Drag and Drop the framework on Embedded Binaries.. then add Run Script on Build Phases.. add also the path on Build Settings> Framework search paths like this>>  $(PROJECT_DIR)/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks   add also other library needed for RealmSwift.... On the project make sure your import is RealmSwift.

Comment: Have tried to follow your suggestion but in my version of Xcode the Add Run Script build phase is greyed out.. If I try to run I now get an error "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error' and a warning 'Directory not found for option -F/Users/userName/Desktop/RealmAppName/RealmSwift/frameworks/Frameworks'